# Export data from Matlab to text file

Tags: matlab, file, csv, text

All, I figured that text file may be the easiest way to export Matlab output to text-file (since `csvwrite` only support numeric values and `xlswrite` can be a pain when handling dates/time).

My Data is composed of dates, timestamps, string (stock name), values (stock values). The data also has column names as a header.
Please, how I can export my data to text-file (which I  'll then read as a `csv`). I did an extensive reading but I am still stuck.

Any advice for a beginner? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> fprintf() is your friend.

However, I am going to write down here a little example:

Write a short table of the exponential function to a text file called exp.txt

```
x = 0:.1:1;
A = [x; exp(x)];

fileID = fopen('exp.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%6s %12s\n','x','exp(x)');
fprintf(fileID,'%6.2f %12.8f\n',A);
fclose(fileID);
```

The first call to fprintf prints header text x and exp(x), and the second call prints the values from variable A.

If you plan to read the file with Microsoft® Notepad, use '\r\n' instead of '\n' to move to a new line. For example, replace the calls to fprintf with the following:

```
fprintf(fileID,'%6s %12s\r\n','x','exp(x)');
fprintf(fileID,'%6.2f %12.8f\r\n',A);
```

MATLAB® import functions, all UNIX® applications, and Microsoft Word and WordPad recognize '\n' as a newline indicator.

View the contents of the file with the type command.

```
type exp.txt

     x       exp(x)
  0.00   1.00000000
  0.10   1.10517092
  0.20   1.22140276
  0.30   1.34985881
  0.40   1.49182470
  0.50   1.64872127
  0.60   1.82211880
  0.70   2.01375271
  0.80   2.22554093
  0.90   2.45960311
  1.00   2.71828183
```

[Here](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) you can find more information and several examples.

Comment: Thanks Leos313. I have seen this example in matlab help and I tried to apply it but it get an error saying  "Error using fprintf
Unable to convert objects of class 'table' into 'double'."  Any idea? Also how I can handle string, dates and timestamps using fprint? Thanks a lot

Comment: share your code so we can try to replicate the error. In any case, it seems you are using "%f " used to print double or floating point values but your data are not double. Have a look in your workspace please and use the exact option for the fprintf instruction.